# Is country domain extention important for local search in Google?

Tags: seo, domains

I own a domain name that uses the `.co` extension and I'm located in France. Someone just advise me to get a `.fr` domain because it would make my local searches in France better.

I personally thought that Google likes brandnames and would'nt care much about extension but do you have any advice on that? Does anyone has back up numbers to back that up?

Comment: Sorry but there is already a number of questions regarding the use of a different ccTLD (Country Top Level Domain), as well as several about EMD (Exact Match Domains) for branding related SEO.

Comment: The simple answer is "Yes". Google care it.

Answer (score 0):

A site hosted with a `.fr` domain is naturally better suited for French-speaking audiences and will be ranked higher on French search engines.

By choosing the hosting IP for your site, you will optimise your ranking in local search engines.

It just depends on IP of your site where it'll be easier to see. Personally... I think I never visited some site that has `.fr` domain.